# Why does React fragment <> </> needs a unique key attribute when rendered in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

So according to the docs, React fragment does not appear on DOM. It doesn't inject any elements to the DOM.

But let's say we want to render elements in a loop whose inside a fragment

```
elementList.map((eachEl) => <> {<span></span>} </>)
```

There is a warning in the console "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop ". If you assign key to the each element, the warning **does not** go away.

```
elementList.map((eachEl) => <> {<span key={uniqeKeyValue} ></span>} </>)
```

If we assign a key to the fragment, the warning goes away.

So, since React fragment does not inject any elements to the DOM, why does it needs a unique key attribute? It looks like assigning key to the each element should be okay.

Why a "ghost element" that doesn't even appear and settled on the DOM needs a unique key?

Comment: Because the key is used by react, not the DOM.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the `key` is not actually needed for the element itself, but for the loop (map loop in your case).

Why is the key useful? So react can know if an element in the list was changed/moved, which one and can also apply optimizations to it and mount/unmount callbacks.

Even though the fragment itself is not rendered, its children are. The fragment is just a logical container.

Read this answer for more info: [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js/43892905#43892905)

Comment: Well since we can force an element to re-render by changing the key value, I thought it's directly relevant to the DOM. So React just needs is to see the loop order has been changed or not.

Comment: @GLHF That's correct, but it's not only for loops. You are right saying you can force to re-render by changing the key value, I used that quite often when I wanted to force elements to re-animate (re-run the css animation: properties). 

Having a different key simply tells React: treat this as a completely new element, discard all previous data.

Comment: @GLHF So, it does force a re-render, but it's just a side-effect and not directly related to the DOM, but to the React element. They `key` is an attribute for a `React.Node`, so you can even force to re-create a React element that doesn't render anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually the `key` is not used in your code. But if there isn't it, you can't run the project correctly.

Because the array distinguish its elements as the `key`.
Of course if you don't need to change any states of its elements, it doesn't care.

But if you wanna change or remove the individual element, you must use the `key`.

Thank you for reading carefully.

Comment: If you wanna know more correctly, you'd better to read React.org